# Embedded one to none relationship ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

Some reason I can't mange to embed one to none relationship with Ember. The problem is for the assembly part in question model  some reason the Serializer tries to find an array.

What can I do to fix that?

[image] http://cl.ly/image/0m3B361K403P

[image]
[image]

Comment: How you requests this payload? Could you write down URL that describes this JSON payload?

Comment: example.com/questions/109

Comment: Is there `store.find` or something like that in App.QuestionsRoute.model hook?

Comment: Yes but what does it has to do with the way associations are setup?

Answer (score -1):

find by query should return a collection

```
questions:[
  {
    id:...
  }
]
```

Comment: Its the show action here. One question has one assembly. It should not have to be represented as an array then right? It would be a has many otherwise no?

Comment: Each question is part of one and only one assembly. So if I would use the async method I would just reference the id of the asssembly. But I want to embed it and I included the full object in the question payload and map it using the EmbeddedRecordMixin. And that is what doesnt seems to work.

Comment: How are you querying for the question?

Comment: this.store.find('question', {limit: 20});

Comment: Could you setup a jsbin with an example with a one way belongsTo embedded relationship without using arrays?

Comment: when you do a find by query, `{limit:20}` ember data has no idea if it's 0 records or 100, so it expects a collection back.  it's unrelated to your embedded record, it's your original response.  It needs to be an array, like I've shown above.

Comment: no no sorry i'm doing "return this.store.find('question', params.question_id);"